# Concatinating variable names in bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to run commands based on the output of a previous command:

```
ifaces=$(ls /sys/class/net)
for i in "${ifaces[@]}"
do
   mac=$(cat /sys/class/net/$i/address)
   echo "$i: $mac"
done
```

but its not working, i'm not sure if my method of concatenation is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in /sys/class/net/*; do
  mac=$(<"$i/address")
  echo "${i##*/}: $mac"
done
```

- `ls` output is formatted for human readability rather than progammatic use. Because filenames can contain literal newlines, but `ls` separates names *with* newlines, it's impossible to both literally represent those names (without escape characters or sequences) and distinguish where on name ends and the next begins. [Don't use it programatically.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
- `$(<file)`, unlike `$(cat "$file")`, doesn't actually need to `fork()` off a subprocess, or `exec()` an external executable. Consequently, it's considerably more efficient.
- `${i##*/}` removes the longest string matching the glob expression `*/` to the variable `$i`. Consequently, it effectively returns only the filename.

Answer (score 0):

When your assigning the output of ls to `ifaces`, wrap it with an array to successfully iterate over the contents:

```
ifaces=($(ls /sys/class/net))
for i in "${ifaces[@]}"
do
   mac=$(cat /sys/class/net/$i/address)
   echo "$i: $mac"
done
```

Comment: Yes, an array is the right thing. No, it shouldn't be populated from `ls`.

Comment: Duly noted, sir.

Comment: See [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) as a reference.